# Best way to set up fence_vmware-soap on centos7

Tags: centos, cluster, pacemaker

I have two node cluster providing nfs services. using pacemaker and corosync. both nodes are using a shared lun.

I created a vsphere user and set up two fence_vmware_soap fence agents. one on each node. My concern is, In a case where the underlying shared storage has issues(disk unmount for 60 seconds) the nodes starts fencing and will cause problems.

How can I set up fence_vmware_soap in a way that, one node still be active during this period without stopping or rebooting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your cluster setup with the quorum option `--auto_tie_breaker`
Below is an exerpt from the official RedHat documentation:

> When enabled, the cluster can suffer up to 50% of the nodes failing at
>   the same time, in a deterministic fashion. The cluster partition, or
>   the set of nodes that are still in contact with the nodeid configured
>   in auto_tie_breaker_node (or lowest nodeid if not set), will remain
>   quorate. The other nodes will be inquorate.